# Настройка VS2017 для работы с Unity

Tags: unity3d, visual-studio-2017

Началось все с того, что не по дефолту не работал автокомплит(для Unity) в VS2017 и VS не подключался к unity. Попробовал перезагрузить проект. И вылетела вот такая ошибка.
[image: VS Erroe]

Сначала я выбрал **первый** пункт и так как .NET Framework 4.6.1 включен в VS2017, то VS подключился к unity, но автокомплит так и не появился + начали сыпаться ошибки, что не подходит платформа для сборки проекта.
Далее сделал *Reimport All* в юнити, чтобы скинуть метинформацию о платформе на дефолт. И попытался снова открыть проект в VS, но при появлении ошибки, уже выбрал второй пункт. Тут VS тупо открыл окно c bing.com. Как же правильно настроить VS для работы с Unity?

**VS2017 15.5.2 + Tools for Unity, Unity 2017.2.1**

Answer (score 0):

В общем, необходимо было установить дополнительно [.NET Framework 3.5](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/visual-studio-sdks)

Comment: нет такого слова "вообщем"